Sending a message to the telegram channel via the telegram bot
I am creating a small project for my own use and I want it to automatically receive notifications in the form of messages in the telegram channel.
I completed all the preliminary steps in the telegram: I created a bot and a chat, added a bot to the chat as an administrator. I received a token and a chat id.
Next, I tried to realize several versions of the code, but none of them work for me.

First variant

Here I get an error:

DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'winhttp.dll' or one of its dependencies: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

public string TelegramSendMessage(string msg)
        {
           string urlString = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={CHATID}&text={msg}";
           WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
           return webclient.DownloadString(urlString);
        }


Second variant

Here I get an error:

The type initializer for 'System.Net.CookieContainer' threw an exception

private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async void SendMessageToChannel(string messageText)
    {
        try
        {
            var url = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage";
            var payload = new
            {
                chat_id = CHATID,
                text = messageText
            };

            var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Print($"Messange send to a chat {CHATID}: {messageText}");
            }
            else
            {
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Print($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {responseBody}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Print($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


Third variant

I don't get any error here, the logs show "Success", but there are no messages in the telegram channel.
public void PostRequest(string msg)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={CHATID}&text={msg}";
                var response = Http.Get(url);
                
                Print(url);
                
                if (response.IsSuccessful)
                {
                    msg += ": Success";
                    Print("Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    msg += ": Error";
                    Print("Error");
                }
            }
            
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                msg += ": EXCEPTION: " + e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace;
            }
        
        }

I have not been able to find a solution for these errors on my own. And to be honest, I got the feeling that I'm basically doing something wrong, because several different ways don't work for me.
Could you help me finish at least 1 of the code options that will be easier to fix in your opinion.

It turned out that I had been using the wrong chat_id all this time. I used the numeric id like -100X...X, but I needed a letter id, which is indicated in the channel description and starts with @.
